# Send data from child to parent component

Tags: javascript, angular, output, angular2-forms

I have a button on my child component that should send information to its parent component but this button is not sending this information. I'm probably missing something but I still didn't notice it.

Here's the code from the button inside my child component (there are two buttons: `selectPessoaJuridica` and `selectPessoaFisica`:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormArray, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {FinalizaDisputaService} from '../services/finaliza-disputa.service';
import {FinalizaDisputaComponent} from './finaliza-disputa.component'

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'titular',
    templateUrl: 'dados-titular.component.html'
})
export class TitularComponent {
    // we will pass in address from App component
  @Input('group')
  public titularForm: FormGroup;
  @Input() submitted:any;
  @Input() indexNumber:any;
  @Output() modelChanged = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  public isJuridica = false;
  classe = {
    pessoa_fisica: 'selected',
    pessoa_juridica: ''
  };
  
  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder, private finalizaAcordo:FinalizaDisputaService) {} 
   
  selectPessoaFisica(e:boolean){
    e = false;
    this.classe.pessoa_fisica = "selected";
    this.isJuridica = false;
    this.classe.pessoa_juridica = "";
    this.modelChanged.emit(e)
  }

  selectPessoaJuridica(e:boolean){
    e = true;
    this.classe.pessoa_fisica = "";
    this.classe.pessoa_juridica = "selected";
    this.isJuridica = true;
    console.log("ativou", e)
    this.modelChanged.emit(e);
  }
}
```

So, what this should do is notify the parent that `e` is now false.

This is the html from parent component:

```
<titular (modelChanged)="recebeValidators($event)" [indexNumber]="indice" [submitted]="submitted" [group]="formDadosBancarios.controls.dados_titular.controls[i]"></titular>
```

And this is the code from parent component where I should receive the value from `e` (`recebeValidators` ):

```
import { Component, OnChanges, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormArray, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, AbstractControl, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';
import { FinalizaDisputaService } from '../services/finaliza-disputa.service';
import {DisputaService} from '../../disputas/services/disputas.service';
import { dadosAcordo } from '../model/dados-acordo.interface';
import { TitularComponent } from './dados-titular.component';
import {Routes, RouterModule, Router, ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'detalhes',
  templateUrl: `finaliza-disputa.component.html`,
  providers: [FinalizaDisputaService]
})

export class FinalizaDisputaComponent implements OnInit {
  public dados: dadosAcordo;
  disputa:any;
  public formDadosBancarios: FormGroup;
  public submitted: boolean;
  public events: any[] = [];
  public servError: any;
  public indice = 0;
  public loading = false;
  soma = 0;
  public servSuccess: any;
  @Input() e:boolean;
  cpf_REGEXP = /^\d+$/;

  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder, private service:DisputaService, private finalizaAcordo: FinalizaDisputaService,
   private route:ActivatedRoute, private router:Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      let id = params['id'];
      this.service
        .buscaPorId(id)
        .subscribe(disputa => {
          this.disputa = disputa;
          console.log(disputa.campanha);
          console.log(this.disputa.propostas_realizadas);
        },
        erro => console.log(erro));
    })

    this.formDadosBancarios = this._fb.group({
      id: [''],
      termos_condicoes: [false, Validators.requiredTrue],
      dados_titular: this._fb.array([
        this.initTitular()
      ])
    })
  }
  /**
  * initTitular- Inicializa o grupo de formulário dinâmico e suas validações
  * @returns  ''
  */
  initTitular() {
    return this._fb.group({
      titular: ['', [<any>Validators.required, <any>Validators.minLength(3)]],
      cnpj: [''],
      cpf: ['', <any>Validators.required],
      data_nasc: ['', <any>Validators.required],
      agencia: ['', <any>Validators.required],
      banco: ['', <any>Validators.required],
      conta: ['', <any>Validators.required],
      tipo: ['', <any>Validators.required],
      pessoa_juridica: [false],
      valor_deposito: ['']
    })
  }
  // this is where I receive e

  recebeValidators(model: dadosAcordo, e: any) {
    console.log("test", e);
    const array = <FormArray>this.formDadosBancarios.get('dados_titular');
    const cpf = array.at(this.indice).get("cpf");
    const cnpj = array.at(this.indice).get('cnpj');
    const data_nasc = array.at(this.indice).get('data_nasc');
    const cpfCtrl: AbstractControl = this.formDadosBancarios.get(['dados_titular', this.indice, 'cpf']);
    const pessoa_juridicaCtrl: AbstractControl = this.formDadosBancarios.get(['dados_titular', this.indice, 'pessoa_juridica'])
    const cnpjCtrl: AbstractControl = this.formDadosBancarios.get(['dados_titular', this.indice, 'cnpj']);
    const data_nascCtrl: AbstractControl = this.formDadosBancarios.get(['dados_titular', this.indice, 'data_nasc']);
    const reqValidators: ValidatorFn[] = [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.cpf_REGEXP)];
    if (e == true) {
      data_nascCtrl.clearValidators();
      cpfCtrl.clearValidators();
      cnpjCtrl.setValidators(reqValidators);
    }else{
      cnpjCtrl.clearValidators();
      cpfCtrl.setValidators(reqValidators);
      data_nascCtrl.setValidators(reqValidators);
    }
    data_nascCtrl.updateValueAndValidity();
    cpfCtrl.updateValueAndValidity();
    cnpjCtrl.updateValueAndValidity();
  }
```

But instead of printing `false` it is printing `undefined`. Can someone help me? thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're shadowing a class attribute with the function parameter "e" in the "recebeValidators" function.

The code:

```
console.log("test", this.e);
```

should actually be:

```
console.log("test", e);
```

To rule out the possibility of a possible casting error in the EventEmitter, try not reusing the parameter function. Example:

```
selectPessoaFisica(e:any) {
    e = false;
    this.modelChanged.emit(e)
}
```

could be rewritten as:

```
selectPessoaFisica() {
    this.modelChanged.emit(false);
}
```

There's also an extra parameter in the receiving function:

This:

```
recebeValidators(model: dadosAcordo, e: boolean) {
```

Should be:

```
recebeValidators(e: boolean) {
```

Comment: Make sure you check which variable you're printing on the console. Everything might be working perfectly, but you might be using "this.e" (a class attribute) instead of "e" (the function argument).

Comment: Yes, I was making some tests and forgot to remove the `this` but even removed it stills printing `undefined` :(. Thanks anyway

Comment: It should be working. I just tested it in my machine and it worked. Maybe if you paste your current source code we could spot the mistake you're making. It's probably some small typo or casting issue.

Comment: ok, I'll edit the question and paste the whole code from the child component

Comment: I've updated the question, see if you can help please

Comment: The recebeValidators function is receiving the wrong arguments. Either recebeValidators(model: dadosAcordo, e: any)  should be  recebeValidators(e: any)  or the code (modelChanged)="recebeValidators($event)"  should be something similar to (modelChanged)="recebeValidators(null, $event)". The variable $event is what is emitted by the EventEmitter - in your case it's a boolean.

Comment: Thank you very much, I put the `(modelChanged)="recebeValidators(null, $event)"` and it worked like a charm

Comment: Don't mention it :)

Answer (score 0):

You should type casting it

```
@Output() modelChanged = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
```

Also you are referring a wrong variable and you should be passing only one argument as it is in the parent component and remove the this keyword

```
recebeValidators(e: boolean) {
    console.log("test", e);
}
```

Comment: Oh yes, I was doing some tests and forgot to remove the `this`. Anyway I cast it like you said but I am still getting undefined :(

Comment: where do you get the undefined on `emit` or `console` update the post with screenshot

Comment: how can I update the child component as you didnt mention in your post. update it I will fix it for you

Comment: Sorry, I didn´t get you, you want me to put the html from the child component?

Comment: Sent you a message